# Printing row of a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to label rows and columns of my matrix.

I can create columns but I can't seem to properly create rows

Here's what I've done:

```
matrix = [[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,0,1]]
row = 0
col = 0
dim = len(matrix)
for i in range(dim):
    print "\t", "col",i,

for r in range(0,dim):
    print
    for c in range(0,dim):
        print "\t", matrix[r][c],
```

Anyone have a good idea?

This is the result i get

```
col 0   col 1   col 2
1       0       1
1       0       1
1       0       1
```

I'm looking to print:

```
      col 0     col 1   col 2
row0    1       0       1
row1    1       0       1
row2    1       0       1
```

Comment: how does the result of your print deviate from the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matrix = [[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,0,1]]
print '\t' + '\t'.join('col{}'.format(i) for i in xrange(len(matrix[0])))
for i,row in enumerate(matrix):
    print 'row{}\t'.format(i) + '\t'.join(str(x) for x in row)
```